# iPad - share and lock geolocation

Tags: ios, ipad, geolocation, mdm

I work for a small/medium size city and we want the garbage collectors to use an application on iPad during their collect to fill a little survey on what they collect.

Aside of this application, **we want to use the iPad to monitor the geolocation of the trucks. (knowing the iPad will be fixed inside the truck)**

We would like to be sure that the geolocation cannot be disabled by the driver and also to be able to monitor all its gelocation data remotely.

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

**Edit:**

Deploying a MDM server seems over our knowledge and capabilities right now. Is there a way to prevent a user from changing iPad settings like enabling/disabling geolocation? Maybe by using a password? There is some 3rd party apps like [FollowMee](https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/followmee-gps-location-tracker/id640133448) and [Save Location GPS](https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/save-location-gps/id1296151414). Is there a way to use such app and prevent a user to disable it?

Comment: The keyword here probably is MDM. Are these iPad managed centrally by an IT department?

Comment: Some MDM developers to look at: [JAMF](https://www.jamf.com), [Apple Server](https://www.apple.com/macos/server/), [Meraki](https://meraki.cisco.com/products/systems-manager). There are others. I've worked with all three products and my institution is currently using JAMF to manage Mac laptops and iPads.

Comment: @nohillside unfortunately, there is no expertise/knowledge with iPad in our TI department, so we are left alone to manage the devices

Comment: Is there a solution that would not need mdm? Maybe just a 3rd party app ?

Comment: 3rd party apps can‘t enforce GPS/geolocation settings.

Comment: Ok I see, deploying a mdm server seems over our knowledge and capabilities right now. Is there a way to prevent a user from changing iPad settings like enabling/disabling geolocation? Maybe by using a password?